# CSS Mask not functioning over a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website, I have a disclaimer pop-up that appears(for users to click on I agree) masking the home page with some 'opacity' and it masks the image and the text on the homepage perfectly.The CSS is below. When I changed the image into a slideshow of few images, the mask and the pop-up goes beneath the slideshow hiding the popup window(but the mask applies to text, just not the image div). How can I make the slideshow also be masked and can be seen without a transparent mask only when 'I Agree' is Clicked ? Does it have to do anything with the type of slideshow? I hope I do not have to post the script.Let me know if I do.Thanks.

```
       #mask 
       {
       position: absolute;
       left:0;
       top:0;
       z-index:99;
       background-color:#666666;
       filter:alpha(opacity=60);
       opacity: 0.6;
       -moz-opacity:0.6;
       }
```

The images below are before and after I put up a slideshow

[image: pop-up over mask on top of image&text]

[image: pop-up and mask beneath the image of a slideshow]

Comment: The z-index of that slider is probably above 99

Comment: I can't tell where the mask is and where the slide show is. What's the css for the slideshow? How is your html structured? Most likely it is a z-index issue

Comment: The webpage is usually white, so the gray part you see below the white popup is the mask. It's a j-query slideshow. And I only have a css for slideshow as width:980 and height :339. The image you see 'ourpeople' is one of the images on the slideshow. how do i solve the z-index issue. Do I have to include anything in the slider css ?

Comment: You probably need to place a display: relative; inside the css for the slider, then place the z-index. Once you have done that and if it still doesnt work, I would put your mask on body with position: absolute; then use width 100% height 100% you need to make sure your mask is at the top of everything in the DOM. As well I would append the mask into the site so that you dont have to constantly code it. Then loop for when users enter the site.

Comment: As you guys pointed out, The Z-Index on the j-query for the slideshow was more than 99 on mask. So increasing the zindex of mask solved the problem. Thanks.